# Bitcoin faucet bot

Tags: bitcoin

I'm looking for a Bitcoin faucet bot where I only type my address once and then only solve the CAPTCHA.

I've found a lot of programs online, but they contain viruses and stuff like that.

Do you know some clean and working Web app or software for Raspbian (preferred) or Windows?